# Custom mailto: link using Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, mailto

I am working with project using Spring and Thymeleaf.
I have list of users. I would like to create contact link using mailto:

```
<a href="mailto:name@email.com">
```

I am displaying list of users like this:

```
<tr th:each="users : ${users}">
    <td th:text="${users.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${users.firstname}"></td>
    <td th:text="${users.lastname}"></td>
    <td th:text="${users.email}"></td>
</tr>
```

So what I would like to achieve is that mailto suits every new professor and his email without me writing it manually.
I am thinking if is possible to write something like this:

```
<td><a th:href = "mailto:${users.email}">
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try the following code:

```html
<td><a th:href="'mailto:' + ${users.email}">Send email </a></td>
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks :)

Comment: See my answer below how to do this safely using link syntax (with proper escaping done by framework)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this more safely and with extra parameters using link syntax:

```html
<td><a th:href="@{mailto:{to}(to=${users.email})}">Send email </a></td>
```

This allows you to also pass CC, Subject and Body:

```html
<td><a th:href="@{mailto:{to}(to=${users.email},subject=${subj},body=${body})}">Send email </a></td>
```